# How to validate date format in spring form without using Annotation?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

addEmployee.jsp

```html
<form:form id="bookForm" modelAttribute="employee" method="post" action="${baseURL}employee/saveemployee" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="publishedOn" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Birth Date
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <form:input path="personalInformation.dateOfBirth" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" class="datepicker form-control" />
      <form:errors path="personalInformation.dateOfBirth"></form:errors>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateOfJoining" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Date Of Joining</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <form:input path="dateOfJoining" placeholder="dateOfJoining" class="form-control" />
      <form:errors path="dateOfJoining"></form:errors>

    </div>
  </div>
</form:form>
```

This is jsp form in which i have to validate date feilds
whenever i click on save button it gives null pointer exception.

2)EmployeeAddController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveemployee",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee")Employee employee,BindingResult result,Errors e,ModelMap map){ 


        employeeValidatorobj.validate(employee,e);
        if(e.hasErrors())
        {
            map.addAttribute("employee",employee);
            return "addEmployee";
        }

        else{
    System.out.println("inside save");
      System.out.println(employee.getPersonalInformation().getFirstName());
         map.addAttribute("employee",new Employee());    

       iEmployeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        map.addAttribute("message", "EmployeeAdded sucessfully");
       return "employeeList";   
    }
    }
```

This is controller here i am checking if form has errors or not.`

3)emolyeeValidator.java

```
public class EmployeeValidator implements Validator {

private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;


private static final String DATE_PATTERN="((?:19|20)\\d\\d)/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/([12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])";
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {

    return Employee.class.equals(arg0);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

        // Employee employee=new Employee();
    Employee employee = (Employee) obj;


       String date=employee.getDateOfJoining().toString();
       if (!date.matches(DATE_PATTERN)) {

           pattern=pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN);
           matcher=pattern.matcher(date);
           if(matcher.matches()){
               errors.rejectValue("dateOfJoining", "dateOfJoining.incorrect","enter correct dateOfJoining");
           }

    }
```

This is employeeValidator class for custome validation of date but when i am try to save record it gives null pointer exception.i have also mapped employeevalidator in bean.and whenever iam trying to validate with .equals() string  method then it gives exception on jsp page string cannot convert into java.util.Date.please check code and suggest me how to check condition in employeeValidator for date format (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: This should be tagged java, not javascript.

Comment: Thanks.by mistake i have selected javascript instead java.